# How to add a notification next to custom admin menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, push-notification, wordpress-theming

I want to show a notification bubble next to a custom menu name on admin dashboard.

It's a custom admin menu, And the notification will be showing a custom value from the Database.

Something like when there is a new WordPress update.

[image: WordPress New Update Notification Screenshot]

I viewed some question, But they were related to posts and not custom menus.

How to do that?

Comment: Please elaborate you want to notify if there is new custom menu item?

Comment: I can add a new custom menu, I want to show a notification bubble next to that menu that  shows a custom value from the DB

Comment: Just like in the screenshot attached

Comment: So for example adding a new menu beneath the settings menu, And show the notification bubble next to that menu, Like that one next to updates and plugins